# vb.net how can i get the name of the textfile saves in the folder?

Tags: vb.net

How can i get the textfile name in my folder?

```
 Dim fileNames = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\K3K3Pro\Ini\", ?*textfilename*?, "*.txt")
```

Comment: The second parameter should be a SearchOption enum. What do you mean with that text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your code file

```
Imports System.IO
```

Uses the `Directory.GetFiles` method to get an array of all files that match your pattern. Then extract the file name from each item in the array with `Path.GetFileName`

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim folderPath = "C:\Users\***\Documents\TextNotes"
    Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt")
    For Each filePath In files
        Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
        Debug.Print(fileName)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: TextNotes" is the name of the filename?

Comment: i just want that the filename is dynamic

Comment: No, that is the name of a directory. I just used that path to test with. You will need to provide a valid directory path.